# How to set up python 3.6.3 so it can be a default project interpreter in PyCharm?

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm

I was using python 3.5.2 as my default project interpreter in PyCharm. Just recently I have installed latest version of python 3.6.3 for Ubuntu and I wanted to set it up as my default project interpreter in PyCharm. However, I were unable to do so. Here is the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ToITv.png)  of the problem.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The error looks like a broken PyCharm installation. Find that `setuptools-28*` file the error is referencing and use `file` or `tar` or something to figure out whether the tarball is broken.

You could also try renaming the file to see if that gets PyCharm to redownload it or something.